# Set Redshift Cluster Visibility with Boto3

Tags: amazon-redshift, boto3

Is there any way of setting a cluster as visible to all users on creation through code?
I am using python boto3 to set up a Redshift client and creating a cluster with this. The cluster is created with no problems as I'm able to interact with it but I cannot see it in my AWS console.

I am basically looking for something like `set_visible_to_all_users()` of EMR. [Docs for EMR function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.set_visible_to_all_users)

Boto3 documentation for Redshift doesn't seem to have anything of this kind on either create_cluster() or as a separate function. [Docs for Redshift.create_cluster()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift.html#Redshift.Client.create_cluster).

Comment: Are you in the correct region in the console?

Comment: Straight to the point. That was the issue :)

Comment: Great, added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you can't hide or unhide Redshift Clusters like that.

You're probably just in the wrong region in the AWS Console.